# Blockquote reflows fenced code blocks

Tags: bug, editor, code-block, blockquote

When using the `”` button to blockquote someone else's words (presumably also when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, if that wasn't the browser quit key), the quoted material is reflowed, by design.  I don't particularly like it, but I can accept that for text.

- This reflow isn't applied to code that's indented four spaces.  That's **good** - the layout of code is usually significant, and I don't want it broken.
- However, the reflow *is* applied to code that's enclosed by ```` ``` ```` fences.  That's **bad**, particularly when the fence has a highlighter hint, because I don't want to have to convert that to an indented code block.

This is particularly important on [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) where pretty much every answer addresses code fragments from the question.

This isn't the same as [Blockquote rewrap destroys code](/q/171197/313677), nor as [Code is incorrectly wrapped when applying blockquote style](/q/108092/313677) despite the similar titles.

Please can the editor be fixed so that **when blockquoting fenced code, the code is protected from reflow** just like indented code is?

Comment: As a workaround, I tend to just not blockquote code snippets and instead indicate attribution in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Laurel.  That doesn't work quite so well in review, where we often tend to alternate between OP code and suggested replacement several times - it would make it a bit harder for readers to see "at a glance" which is which.   But it does seem easier (as author) than my current workaround of manually inserting `> ` (or, for larger blocks, copying into a proper editor to make the change and then pasting back to the question).

Comment: Honestly, I wish it wouldn't reflow at all. Makes large quotes particularly tedious to re-work afterwards.

Comment: To clarify - I don't mind it reflowing lines, but I hate when it folds up paragraphs, just discards the double return.